# Как отключить таймер на 5 секунд?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Создал на bootstrap slider. Авто таймер слайда не работал. Поэтому написал следующий скрипт:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
    $('#next').click();
    }, 3000);
 });
```

Но как сделать, чтобы если нажата кнопка "prev", то остановить таймер на 5 секунд. А затем вновь начал крутиться?

Comment: переведите свой комментарий в ответ, плюсну и приму ) Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Схематически - [как-то так](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/Ct64c/)